# How to make a GET call within a JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to display a countdown timer on my page while I do some backend processing and fetching of data in PHP. The following code does a good job of displaying a countdown timer:

```
<h3>
  Hang on, we're fetching the data ... <span id="countdown">10</span> seconds
</h3>

<!-- JavaScript part -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Total seconds to wait
    var seconds = 10;
    
    function countdown() {
        /*
            Call GET endpoint to check on status of data
        */

        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            window.location = "https://example.com";
        } else {
            // Update remaining seconds
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = seconds;
            // Count down using javascript
            window.setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
        }
    }
    
    // Run countdown function
    countdown();
    
</script>
```

The `window.location` in the `countdown()` method needs to change depending on the outcome of the PHP processing on the backend. It should either update the window.location variable with the destination URL or update it to the "coming soon" URL.

It's a simple GET endpoint to check on the status of the data. How do I call this endpoint within the `countdown()` method in order to capture the status?

Comment: Send a simple [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) request (see "Step 3 - A Simple Example" for a quick overview).

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? Sorry, not skilled in JavaScript or Ajax.

Comment: See the example on the link I shared. It would contain the same code I would write as a working example.

Comment: I assume you got downvoted because googling "How to make a GET call within JavaScript" would have gotten you the same link I got you (or similar).